# Entity Framework classes to diagram

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity, diagram, edmx

I have a bunch of classes with navigation properties and foreign keys. How can I visualise the relationships between these classes.

Comment: If you use VS it has ability to display edmx diagrams autogenerated. This is not really a question that SO can solve for you - it borders `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.` which is explicity cited as "off-topic" here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Google/Wikipedia UML and try VS features would be my advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Entity Framework 6, you can use the "EF Power Tools" to create a EDMX diagram from your DbContext.

If you use VS, you can use "Class Diagram"

If you use EF Core, you can use EF Core Power Tools to create a diagram of your DbContext

Answer (score 0):

short question, short answer: you need a DbContext then you can use Entity Framework power tools which you can find [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EntityFramework6PowerToolsCommunityEdition).

> When right-clicking on a file containing a derived DbContext class, the following context menu functions are available:
>
> - View Entity Data Model (Read-only)
> - View Entity Data Model XML
> - View Entity Data Model DDL SQL
> - Generate Views